# SHACL Rule Execution on New Instances?

Tags: jena, topbraid-composer, shacl

I have an application wherein I used SPIN constructors as a means to implement Event/Condition/Action (ECA) policies.  ECA is one classic construct for policies.  The Event, in this case, was always the assertion of a class on an individual which caused that class's SPIN constructors to run on that new individual.  The Condition was the pattern expressed in my SPARQL `WHERE` clause, and the Action was provided by assertions in a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` clause.  My understanding is that the SPIN constructor would only run on the new individual of the class, not on all individuals of the class.

I'm now looking into switching to SHACL as the successor to SPIN.  I'm developing in TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition, and I could implement using the Jena SHACL API.

Suppose that I express an ECA policy as a SHACL shape and target a class via the `sh:targetClass` SHACL predicate.  Let's say my target class is `family:Person`.  Every time I assert a new `family:Person` individual, I'd like to run my ECA policy (expressed as a SHACL shape) on *only* that new individual.  I'm aware that a listener could be used to sense new class membership.  I'm also aware that methods such as `RuleUtil.executeRules()` could be used once a change is sensed to execute all rules on all targeted nodes (individuals of the `family:Person` class, in my example).  But, **is there a way to apply SHACL shapes to *only* the new individuals of a targeted class?**  In my application, individuals would be accumulated over time and could become quite numerous.  I'm concerned that the computational load of running shapes repeatedly against the same, old, unaltered individuals would become significant.

Answer (score 3):

A possible way to solve your problem is to use a "third-party" relation to mark the individuals that have been processed by the rule, and use such marking in a sh:condition referenced by the rule.

You would obtain something like that:

```
:MyCondition
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:comment "The condition preventing re-application of the rule";
    sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
    sh:sparql [
        sh:select """
        PREFIX : <http://example.com/ns#>
        PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
        SELECT $this
        WHERE {
            # Here, the $this will be the focus node of the target class
            $this :hasMarking "true"^^xsd:boolean.
        }
        """;
    ].

:MyRule
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:comment "The rule should be applied only once";
    sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
    sh:rule [
        a sh:SPARQLRule ;
        sh:condition :MyCondition ;
        sh:construct """
            PREFIX : <http://example.com/ns#>

            CONSTRUCT {
                $this :hasMarking "true"^^xsd:boolean.
            } WHERE {
                $this :property :object.
                # Here, the body of the rule
                # ...
            }
        """;
    ].
```

In this case, the marking is based on a simple boolean property, but it may also be based on a more useful information captured by the rule body, and representative of the rule result, i.e. `$this :property :Object`, where `property` is only inferred by your rule.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of "new individuals" sounds application-specific and depends on the execution logic. Nobody forces anyone to use sh:targetClass neither is it required to run all rules all the time. You can control this on API level. Instead of sh:targetClass, you could use some other property of your choice such as ex:constructedClass and implement a Java-based function that takes the new instances as input and follows the property to find all applicable shapes. If you think there is a generic pattern here, we could add them to a de-facto extension namespace such as dash:

Comment: Looking more closely at the RuleUtil.executeRules method, I see an alternative method signature that takes RDFNode focusNode as its first argument.  It seems that if I can get my listener to produce the new individual, then I could use the executeRules(RDFNode focusNode, Model shapesModel, Model inferencesModel, ProgressMonitor monitor) signature to target only my new instance.  Does this sound viable?  If so, then I may attempt to code an answer to my own question along these lines and post it.

Comment: Yes correct. And if the RuleUtil methods are not flexible enough (they are just utilities in the end) you can bypass them and go straight into the RuleEngine API.